# Hide all tabs content jQuery UI tabs onload

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to load just tabs when page is loaded?

Sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/MWtMR/2/

It should only display text if I click on some tab. Divs #tab1, #tab2, #tab3 should remain hidden until I click on one of the tabs.

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/MWtMR/3/

I found it by setting collapsible: it is true that I can click and it will close that tab content. How can I make this behavior on load of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `selected` option to `-1`

```
$('#tabvanilla').tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'}, selected: -1 });
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MWtMR/4/

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Since jQuery UI 1.10, you'll have to use parameter `active` instead of `selected`.

```
$('#tabvanilla').tabs({ active: false, collapsible: true });
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active for details.