# UI Tabs with all tabs hidden WITHOUT "active: false"

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

For my design it is crucial that all tabs are ***closed*** when the page initially loads. The default is, however, to display the first tab.

These two posts tackled the same question and solved the problem by setting

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({collapsible: true, active: false });
```

[Hide all tabs content jQuery UI tabs onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144353/hide-all-tabs-content-jquery-ui-tabs-onload)

[Initiate jQuery UI Tabs with no tabs active and all panels hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595221/initiate-jquery-ui-tabs-with-no-tabs-active-and-all-panels-hidden)

(Since jQuery UI 1.10, there is the parameter `active` instead `selected`.) However, somehow this setting ***conflicts*** with a [slider plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider) that is in one of my tabs and also uses the parameter `active`

Consequently, I can't use `active: false` or need a way to make the option specific to the tabs only.

I appreciate every help.

http://jsfiddle.net/WRn7q/1/ - with `active: false` enabled, but without the slider plugin

Comment: Can you update your fiddle to include the slider? It will be easier to help with all the relevant code.

Comment: I tried... however it seems that the plugin does not load in jsfiddle - neither with active: false enabled nor disabled.
http://jsfiddle.net/TEhVp/

Comment: Here is the project draft http://people.rit.edu/~jxk7227/jukoegel.com/Index.html (All tabs should be closed)

Comment: You haven't included any of the external js or css files in the fiddle

Comment: Mh, I thought I did. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/TEhVp/1/
Sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `$(window).load()` to `$(document).ready()` and then added `active: false` to the tabs and it worked.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/TEhVp/2/)**

```
//Load Orbit
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#featured').orbit({
        directionalNav: true,
        animationSpeed: 800,
        advanceSpeed: 4000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        bullets: false
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the right clue. However, for me it worked only when I set `$(window).load()` for both plugins. Now, I have an ugly flashing tab when the page loads. There is some collision with the `active` parameter between the two js.

Comment: Yeah! Resolved the issue with positioning which made it flash at -9999px and then moved it back into the right place.